# Migrate Application Client from one email address to another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I migrate my existing App projects/clients (preserving the same client id, secret and all associated data) from one email address to another.

Background: One of our apps was created on a standard gmail account but now we would like to host it on a company email address. We would not like to prompt the user to reaccept terms they've already agreed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gmail account add the company email address as an owner. It will give full access. If you want to can remove the gmail account and the company email address will take over ownership.